# Install AIDE in Slackware in 14.2

Tags: package-managers, slackware

I want to install aide in slackware but the package manager cannot download aide package. I tried the code below with no luck :

```
slackpkg install aide
```

The output shows :

```
Looking for aide in package list. Please wait . . . Done

No packages match the pattern or install. Try

/usr/sbin/slackpkg reinstall|upgrade
```

How will I fixt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock Slackware packages tree doesn't contain aide binary package.
slackbuilds.org has slackbuild script for it here:
https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/aide/
So read the README and README.Slackware files and build and install package as usual (manual or using sbopkg from sbopkg.org).

With sbopkg:

`# sbopkg -r -i aide`

Manual:

```
# mkdir /tmp/bld; cd /tmp/bld
# wget https://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.2/system/aide.tar.gz
# tar xf aide.tar.gz
# cd aide
##read README and README.Slackware
# . *info
# wget $DOWNLOAD
# bash *Build
# upgradepkg --install-new /tmp/aide-$VERSION-*t?z
```

Comment: I tried running the manual method. The last command throws an error : Cannot install /tmp-aide-0.16-*t?z: file not found. Do I have to replace something in the command?

Comment: As an edit to the last command, cd /tmp, make sure a file with a prefix "aide" exist with an extension tgz. Then run upgradepkg --install-new <aide_file.tgz>. Replace aide_file.tgz with your package name.

Comment: Yes, it was typo in the path, '/tmp-' unstead of '/tmp/'. Fixed.